# tcpdump catching mac and rssi in linux

Tags: linux, rss, wifi, tcpdump, sniffer

I'm trying to use a wlan adapter (TP-link TL-WN722N) in monitor mode to pick up RSS from signals in the environment (both beacons and clients). What I would like to do is to get the MAC address and RSS value into my own code somehow (preferably python). I'm planning to use these values for a rough estimate of locations of nearby devices.

I've looked into scapy, but it does not seem to provide RSS values.

tcpdump seems to be able to get both values, but I have been unable to catch client devices. 
Is it possible? 
If so can I filter MAC and RSS somehow?

Comment: I got it working with tcpdump!

First setup a monitor mode adapter:
'sudo iw phy phy1 interface add moni0 type monitor'
'sudo ifconfig moni0 up'

See [this guide for more details](http://pharos.ece.utexas.edu/wiki/index.php/How_to_Measure_the_Received_Signal_Strength_of_WiFi_Beacons)

You can find my project [here](https://github.com/ninc/wifi-client-logger).

Answer (score 0):

I got it working with tcpdump!

To setup a monitor mode adapter, you first need to check which interface to use:

```
iw list
```

Select the correct phy (for me its phy1) and create an adapter (I called it moni0):

```
sudo iw phy phy1 interface add moni0 type monitor
```

Then add your adapter to the ifconfig:

```
sudo ifconfig moni0 up
```

See [this guide for more details](http://pharos.ece.utexas.edu/wiki/index.php/How_to_Measure_the_Received_Signal_Strength_of_WiFi_Beacons).

I used the following params for tcpdump to get the values that I needed. (you can pipe the output to your program, main.py in my case):

```
sudo tcpdump -n -e -tttt -vvvv -i moni0 | python main.py
```

You can find my project [here](https://github.com/ninc/wifi-client-logger).